# Calculated Column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables (users and reports). Users store some user information including their IDs  Reports store the list of reports available in the system where the Owner field shows which user owns the report. I have a view that has certain columns from the user table. I would like to have an additional calculated column in the view that will show how many Reports does the user own.

Something like:
SELECT owner, count(*) as ReportsOwned
FROM Reports
GROUP BY owner;

This is the view:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Users_SPO] AS
SELECT DisplayName AS Name,
       ManagedBy AS [Managed By],
       CanBeDeleted AS [Can Be Deleted],
       PrimarySmtpAddress AS Email,
       TeamsEnabled AS [Team Enabled],
       NumberOfChats AS Chats,
       NumberOfConversations AS Conversations,
       SPOActivity AS [SPO Activity],
       SPOStatus AS [SPO Status],
       Notes AS Description,
       WhenCreated AS [Creation Date],
       WhenChanged AS [Change Date],
       ExternalDirectoryObjectId
  FROM dbo.Users
GO
```

Comment: Does your query work?  It would seem to do what you want.

Comment: That looks fine. So you just need to know how to join that into your view? Or rewrite it as a subquery in the view select statement? What help do you need specifically? If you do need sytntax help, it might be useful to see the relevant bits of your view so far.

Comment: Can you please first do a little more research on SQL and define your question a bit clearer?

Comment: I think it was pretty clear. I would like to have a column in my view where I can have a calculated column that shows how many reports does the user have in the Reports table.

Comment: Your question is clear, but this website is not a place where you give requirements and we write code for you -- this website is for answering questions with code you have written.  If you want someone to write code for you hire a consultant.  We are here to help when you have questions -- the amount of work you do should be many times the amount we do.  Otherwise you will find people here don't want to answer your question.  We all know *how* to do this, but this is a simple task in SQL, it should not be a problem for you to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess as you do not define the two tables nor any link between them. I would hope you would have an field in there somewhere.

`CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Users_SPO] AS
SELECT DisplayName AS Name,
       ManagedBy AS [Managed By],
       CanBeDeleted AS [Can Be Deleted],
       PrimarySmtpAddress AS Email,
       TeamsEnabled AS [Team Enabled],
       NumberOfChats AS Chats,
       NumberOfConversations AS Conversations,
       SPOActivity AS [SPO Activity],
       SPOStatus AS [SPO Status],
       Notes AS Description,
       WhenCreated AS [Creation Date],
       WhenChanged AS [Change Date],
       ExternalDirectoryObjectId,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM Reports rp where rp.owner = displayname) as ReportsOwned
  FROM dbo.Users
GO`

Comment: this is a horrible answer it runs in O(n^2)